# How to read line gracefully in python under linux

Tags: python, command-line, stdin

I am writing a short python script to read line from stdin, but when I run it and press keys like home, end, left, right, it doesn't work, it prints the key on the line instead.

I also want to have the feature "up/down" to view history of editing, just like the python interactive console.

Is there an easy way to do this? I tried getch and curses, but seems not easy to do this. trying curses which tangles up my command line window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [GNU readline interface](http://docs.python.org/library/readline.html).